# Writing a conditional statement for this tables

Tags: t-sql, syntax, case, conditional-statements

I have a requirement where I need to write a few lines of case statement to generate a new column, counting the first and the second column to return the result.
In this example I want to check if the second column has more `null`, then return `'semi valid'`

```
ref no       first column      second column      result (new column) 
1234         yes               yes 
1234         null              null
1234         yes               null
```

In this example I want to check if there's no `null` in both, then return `'valid'`

```
ref no       first column      second column      result (new column) 
1234         yes               yes 
1234         yes               yes
1234         yes               yes
```

In this example I want to check if the second column has more `null`, then return `'higher valid'`

```
ref no       first column      second column      result (new column) 
1234         yes               yes 
1234         yes               yes
1234         yes               null
```

In this example I want to check if the first column has more `null`, then return `'not valid'`

```
ref no       first column      second column      result (new column) 
1234         null              yes 
1234         null              yes
1234         null              yes
```

Comment: Improved formatting & title. You didn't specify what language you're using.

Comment: Thanks Federico Grandi, I am using T-sql , the question I have asked need to be implemented to existing view

Comment: I've added TSQL to the tags

Comment: Any advice/answer?